# Starting and Stopping a Beacon Scanner App with Android Beacon Library

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ibeacon, altbeacon

I have built a small app which uses the Android Beacon Library to find nearby beacons when the user starts the app following this tutorial: http://www.software7.com/blog/creating-a-beacon-app-for-android-in-less-than-10-minutes-from-scratch/

If the App is startet and **finds beacons** belonging to the specific region, it **prints information in the console** and also on the text label in the UI.

I am starting and closing the Beacon Manager in my **OnCreate** and **OnDestroy** methods, which is managing the search process.

The App works nicely when I start it **first time**. But when I close it with my arrow back button on the phone and **open it again**, there will be **no more console messages** nor updates on the text label. This also happens when the screen goes to sleep and I have to unlock it again - no console updates, no UI updates.

According to the console messages, the **OnBeaconServiceConnect** is working on resuming the app, but I don't get a log message from **didEnterRegion** nor **setRangeNotifier** again.

I also tried putting the bind and unbinds into OnPause and OnResume, which didn't work out too.

How can I resume the search & find process again correctly? 
Thank you for any help :)

Here's my commented code in case you want to have a short look:

```
package de.mediatoni.beacontut01;

import android.graphics.Region;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.altbeacon.beacon.Beacon;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconConsumer;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconManager;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.BeaconParser;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.Identifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.MonitorNotifier;
import org.altbeacon.beacon.RangeNotifier;

import java.util.Collection;


public class BeaconActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements BeaconConsumer{

    public static final String TAG = "BeaconsEverywhere";
    // Beacon Manager Variable
    private BeaconManager beaconManager;

    //GUI Text Label
    TextView rangeElement;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon);

        // Vars for XML Elements
        rangeElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.range);

        // Instantiate a Beacon Manager via factory method
        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);

        // Tell Library how to decode the signal
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24,d:25-25"));
        // Start the Beacon Manager
        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    // When the Beacon Service starts, search for Beacons with the following Identifier
    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        final org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region = new org.altbeacon.beacon.Region("myBeacons", Identifier.parse("73676723-7400-0000-ffff-0000ffff0005"), null, null);
        beaconManager.setMonitorNotifier(new MonitorNotifier() {
            // If the phone enters a Beacon region
            @Override
            public void didEnterRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "did Enter Region");
                    beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // If the phone leaves a Beacon region
            @Override
            public void didExitRegion(org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "did Exit Region");
                    beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {

            }
        });

        // If the phone finds a Beacon fitting the rules, print it in the console
        beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            //Log out welche beacons in der Nähe sind
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, org.altbeacon.beacon.Region region) {
                for(final Beacon oneBeacon : beacons) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "distance: " + oneBeacon.getDistance() + "id: " + oneBeacon.getId1() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId2() + "/" + oneBeacon.getId3());

                    // Access UI thread and make changes to the UI
                    // Placing rangeElement.setText outside of the Runnable will crash the App
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Change the text label in the UI
                            rangeElement.setText(String.valueOf(oneBeacon.getDistance()));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // When the App gets closed, stop the Beacon Manager
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        beaconManager.unbind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_beacon, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem likely is that you do not get a second entry event when the Activity restarts, because the beacon is still visible and never went out of view.  Starting with Library version 2.8, repeat entry events are suppressed unless there is a corresponding exit event.

In order to get an entry event each time you start monitoring, simply stop monitoring the region before starting monitoring it again.  Like this:

```
beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
```